# Prove or disprove: There exists an element in the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ of order 6.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove: There exists an element in the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ of order 6. By counting formula, since $|\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}|$ is infinite, it seems possible to have an element of order 6. But how to find one? In addition, what is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, please?

Comment: Do you understand what a quotient group is? Because $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is just an ordinary quotient group. It can be viewed as the real numbers modulo $1$.

Comment: I am unable to grasp what actually you mean when you say " since |R/Z| is infinite, it seems possible to have an element of order 6.".. do you mean if a group is infinite it has elements of all orders???

Comment: I think so. Isn't it true?

Comment: @XuS What are the possibly orders for elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ (under addition)?

Comment: No, it’s clearly not true: look at the group $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: It might be useful and easy if you can check this criteria for invertible matrices group.. and yes.. as Mr.Brian said above.. you can see for integers group...

Comment: Order of $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite. The order of any non-zero element in $\mathbb{Z}$ is also infinite. Hence, it cannot have any element of finite order.

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: You can think of your quotient group as follows. The elements of the group are, **sort of**, the numbers in the interval $[0,1)$. Except that when you add you throw away the integer part. So $0.6+0.7=0.3$, and $0.5+0.5=0$. This is a very strong hint.

Comment: Then the example should be $\frac{1}{6}$. Right?

Comment: @XuS : Yes.. You got it.. :)

Comment: Yes, there are elements of any order, same idea. To be precise, the object is $[1/6]$, the equivalence class of $1/6$.

Comment: @XuS what you mean by counting argument?

Comment: Just Lagrange theorem, i.e. the order of an element divides the order of the group. I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the groups we are dealing with are abelian, I will use $+$ as the group operation.

The elements of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ are cosets of the subgroup $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$.  For example, the identity element is the coset $[0]=0+\mathbb Z$, and $[.5]=.5 + \mathbb Z$ is another element.  Note that $[a]=[b]$ if and only if $a-b\in \mathbb Z$.  So $[.5]+[.5]=[1]=[0]$.  Thus, we see that even though both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Z$ are torsion free, the quotient group still has torsion.

I assert that you can rephrase your question as "Does there exist a real number $x$ such that $6x$ is an integer, but no smaller multiple of $x$ is?"  When phrased like this, the question should be easier to answer.  Understanding why the question can be rephrased this way is an important step in understanding $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2):

The group $\mathbb{R}$ under addition is the set of real numbers along with the standard binary operation that takes input $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and gives out $a+b$.

It's a group since it's nonempty, addition is associative, it has an identity (viz., $0$), and every element has an inverse (viz., $r$ has inverse $-r$).

Showing $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a normal subgroup is a nice exercise.

This lets us talk about the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

In particular, we have the original group, but regard elements as the same if they differ by an integer. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2} + 73$ are the same, since they differ by the integer $73$.

Convince yourself, then, that we can view any element of the quotient group as being in $[0, 1)$.

For example, the number $100 + \pi$ is the same here as $\pi - 3 \in [0, 1)$. Can you see why?

Next, convince yourself that the operation is simply addition modulo $1$.

For example, as mentioned in a comment, $0.6 + 0.7 = 0.3$. Does this make sense?

Since your identity is $0$, you are now asking: Is there any element of the quotient group $x$ such that $6x = 0$ under addition modulo $1$, and for which $nx \neq 0$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is less than $6$?

Comment: [for completeness: note also $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition.]

Answer (score 1):

you can prove more general result :

Given positive integer $n$ there exists an element of order $n$ in $\frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Given a positive integer $n$, what is the order of $\mathbb{Z} + \frac{1}{n}$ in $ \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$ ?

Same is true in the 'very  smaller' group $\frac{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Z}}$.